# Why "broad" instead of "large" cross-immunoreactivity?

Tags: immunology, terminology, nomenclature

From the articles I read, expressions like "broad cross-immunoreactivity" pops up a lot. So, I was wondering, why "broad" is used here instead of large? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's about English usage.

Comment: @canadianer Stone correctly identified a scientific buzzword by its somewhat awkward placement. This is not about general English usage.

Comment: @tel It's a stretch to say that the sentence is referring to broadly neutralizing antibodies, especially without more context. Sometimes broad just means broad.

Comment: I vote to re-open, because it fits perfectly under the tag "**terminology**", which is: "How **terms** are used or the **meaning of words** as used in scientific literature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "broad" is a buzzword, a piece of scientific jargon. It's a callback to Broadly Neutralizing Antibodies[1], bNAbs. The basic idea with bNAbs is that they target parts of viral proteins that tend not to mutate or change very much between individual strains of some particular virus.

## Edit:

To clarify, I am not suggesting that an antibody with "broad cross-immunoreactivity" is the same thing as a bNAb. Immunoreactivity and neutralization are not the same thing (although there is some overlap).

> 1: Zwick, M. B., Labrijn, A. F., Wang, M., Spenlehauer, C., Saphire, E. O., Binley, J. M., et al. (2001). Broadly Neutralizing Antibodies Targeted to the Membrane-Proximal External Region of Human Immunodeficiency Virus Type 1 Glycoprotein gp41. Journal of Virology, 75(22), 10892–10905. http://doi.org/10.1128/JVI.75.22.10892-10905.2001

Answer (score 6):

**Broad** means **wide** as in a wide range. Normally, antibodies have one epitope they recognize, i.e., one specific target; they are said to have a **narrow range** of targets.

Some antibodies, however, recognize multiple targets, i.e. the *number of targets* they recognize is *larger* and their **target range** is **widened**. They are said to have a **broad** cross-immunoreactivity.

A '*large*' cross-immunoreactivity, however, is ambiguous, as *'large'* can also imply *'large reactivity'*, and then *'large'* becomes synonymous to *'strong'*. **Wide** is unambiguous as it always implies a **large range**.